# Is it possible to decompress SharpZipLib compressed response via PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, sharpziplib

Environment: Linux / MySQL / PHP

Problem: While connected to a webservice, I am getting a response that is compressed with the SharpZipLib .NET library. As of yet, I have not been able to find a way to decompress these responses outside of a .NET environment.

Does anyone know a way to decompress this in a linux/php environment? Thanks!

Comment: You can try this method to decompress string
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23272388/2648683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another web service provided that provided a non-compressed response. However the information above was useful, just not for this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their API documentation, I see the following compression algorithms that can be used from SharpZipLib which PHP can read: [BZip2](http://php.net/bzread), [Zip ('Deflated'),](http://php.net/gzdeflate) [Zip.Compression](http://php.net/gzuncompress), [GZip](http://php.net/gzread), [Tar](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar), [LZW](http://code.google.com/p/php-lzw/). Some of these are even registered as [stream filters](http://php.net/wrappers.compression), allowing you to chain them in nifty ways such as `file_get_contents('compress.zlib://http://domain/resource')` or `file_get_contents('compress.bzip2://php://stdin')`.